# Firefox bookmarks: want to save page I type, not the redirect

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Using Ubuntu 22.04.2LTS desktop on an Asus laptop (UX305) (and a desktop - same issue)

**EDIT**

*In response to the comment (and presumably the down-voter who may or may not be the same person) which I think misunderstands what I'm asking, very simply - I want to edit the page a Firefox bookmark points to.*

The issue is -

I use Citrix receiver to access a remote server in a hospital.

I type the URL provided to me by the hospital (https://apps.****.nhs.uk/)
(Address concealed by me for confidentiality)

This then redirects to the secure login page at:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/*f**d*f*-**ef-**d*-*f*e-*d*c*b*b**e*/saml*
(numbers replaced by * by me to ensure no breach of confidentiality)

Now if I try to bookmark the https://apps... page, it redirects *before* saving the bookmark (no matter what I try - even if I try to bookmark the page before hitting enter) and when I then try to use that bookmarked landing page I get the error message

```
Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.
AADSTS750054: SAMLRequest or SAMLResponse must be present as query string parameters in HTTP request for SAML Redirect binding.
```

What (I think) I need to do is have the https://apps... page save as the bookmark, not the page it redirects to. If I type in the redirect page directly (https://login...), I get the same error ... so it seems it *has* to go through the redirection process to allow me to access the login page.

Anyone know how to do that (save the URL I type in, not the one it redirects to, or edit the bookmark - either within Firefox or (if I knew where the bookmarks are stored) using a text editor)? I can't do either at the moment - Firefox doesn't have an obvious bookmark edit other than changing the *name*, and I can't find any obvious places where the bookmarks are stored - Mozilla's help pages list a few locations but I can't find the relevant file to edit. I can show where I've looked but don't want to bog down the question with unnecessary detail as it's probably not useful for answering.

Mozilla Firefox was the default installed with Ubuntu, version is 112.0.1 (64-bit).

Happy to provide any other information.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why don't you edit your bookmark and enter the desired (not redirected) URL?

Comment: @mook765 - that’s what I want to do - but Firefox only has an option to edit the name (unless I’ve missed something really obvious!).

Comment: I don't know what you're missing, I can also edtit URL, tags and keyword, just right-click the bookmark and chose `Edit Bookmark...`. Or use `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O` to open the bookmarkmanager, select yout bookmark...

Comment: If you can edit only the name, it's not a bookmark but a folder.